# Is Tkinter included with Python 2.5?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have downloaded python 2.5. I would like to know if Tkinter is included with python or is it a separate download?

Comment: What about you start python and type `import Tkinter`? :)

Comment: Just type what the above comment says.!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is included.

http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

Comment: It depends on where you download from - python.org has it included, but some distributions (i.e. debian-based linux distros) have decided to distribute Tkinter separately.

Comment: You are correct, i assumed he has downloaded it from Python.org, since it's the official website for Python.

Comment: I think it depends on the system. if you work on linux you need to install tcl/tk by yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux just open your terminal and type python and in the `python` interpreter type  `from Tkinter import*` if it doesn't show any error messages you are good to go. You can try this to check every package of python like `Pygame` just replace Tkinter by Pygame